# Project sub document with ConditionalOperators applied - Spring mongo data

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

The document on which the aggregation is being run on has the following structure.

```
{
  "field1" : "value1",
  "field2" : "value2",
  "field3" : "value3"
}
```

along with other irrelevant fields for the current scenario. Note that type of values in field1, field2, field3 are all of type strings.

**WORKING SCENARIO:**

The aggregation has one projection Operation after which the desired output structure of the final document is as follows:

```
{
   "field4" : {
                 "field5" : "value1",
                 "field6" : "value2",
                 "field7" : "value3"
              }
}
```

Able to achieve this with the below query in mongo Db shell:

```
   db.getCollection("testCollection").aggregate(   
   [{
     "$project": {
           "field4": {
                     "field5": "$field1",
                     "field6": "$field2",
                     "field7": "$field3"
                     }
                 }
  }]
  )
```

In spring data mongo terms, able to achieve this with the below code:

```
Aggregation.project()
           .nested(Fields.from(Fields.field("field5", "field1"), 
                               Fields.field("field6", "field2"),
                               Fields.field("field7", "field3")))
```

**PROBLEM SCENARIO**

The requirement now is that if any of the values in field1, field2, or field3 is null, then they get a default value.

Able to achieve this with the below query in mongo Db shell:

```
db.getCollection("testCollection").aggregate(
[{
   "$project": {
           "field4": {
                     "field5": {"$ifNull" :["$field1", ""]},
                     "field6": {"$ifNull" :["$field2", ""]},
                     "field7": {"$ifNull" :["$field3", ""]}
                     }
                 }
}]
)
```

But, when trying to achieve the same in spring data mongo terms, not able to achieve the same.

What has been tried so far:

```
 Aggregation.project()
           .nested(Fields.from(Fields.field("field5", 
           ConditionalOperators.ifNull("field1").then(StringUtils.Empty)), 
                               Fields.field("field6", "field2"),
                               Fields.field("field7", "field3")))
```

but this throws an error saying that the second argument to the Fields.field should be of type java.lang.string, but found ConditionalOperators.ifNull.

**So, what is the right way to achieve the mongo db query in spring data mongo db terminology?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projecting expressions as nested fields is not really well supported in current (2.1.x) Spring Data MongoDB. I've created [DATAMONGO-2353](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2353) to improve this.

```java
Aggregation.project()
  .and((ctx) -> 
    new Document("field5", ifNull("field1").then("").toDocument(ctx))
      .append("field6", ifNull("field2").then("").toDocument(ctx))
  ).as("field4")
```

As of Spring Data MongoDB 2.2.RC1 there is support for [declarative aggregations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.0.RC2/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation), that applies the native aggregation to a repository query method.

```java
@Aggregation("{ '$project': { 'field4' : { 'field5' : { '$ifNull' : ... } } } }")
List<DomainType> projectNested();
```